# How to add text over Slideshow/carousel?

Tags: views, javascript

I've been able to create a simple slideshow using field slideshow, jcarousel and libraries.

But how would I go about add text in the rhs of the images? I would like the text to change depending on the slideshow image.

Comment: Add text in your views - therefore  text changes with slide and related to slide. Then position the text wherever you like using css.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I am new to Drupal. How would I go about adding text to the view? By first adding a text field to the slideshow content type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are using [views](http://drupal.org/project/views) + [views slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) for the slideshow, correct??
And you are using a slideshow content type.

No => use [views](http://drupal.org/project/views) + [views slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) to show your slideshow contents as a slideshow. You can find instructions in its documentation and many videos to help you out(google knows best!! :))

Yes =>

- in views : should show fields and not content
- so you will have 2(or more per your need) fields : image and text(custom text area or say your title)
- Using css you can position your text.

Hope it helps....keep posting your problems in comments...the community will always help you out.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am using the field slideshow module, but will install views slideshow now.

Comment: Any tips on positioning text over the image? Is it ok to use -ve top margin? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Google for 'css position absolute' and this is also a good tutorial on positioning - http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/. -ve margin is not something I would advice on going for, for things like these. The rest I think you should discover for yourself. If you need help, keep posting, community is always ready to help :)